# retrofit 2 dynamically set part parameter name

Tags: android, post, retrofit2, multipartform-data

Can I dynamically set parameter name as a part of a multi-part request using retrofit 2, What I'm exactly looking for is

```
@Multipart
@POST(UPDATE_PROFILE)
Call<SignUp> sendUpdateProfileRequest(
            @Part("profile_img") RequestBody img_file,
            @Part("DYNAMIC_PARAM_NAME") RequestBody first_name,...);
```

where DYNAMIC_PARAM_NAME is like id_seller/id_buyer/id_buyer, rest of parameters and the request URL remains same.

while making call can i achieve such type of function in Activity or Fragment ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try Retrofit's `@PartMap` annotation instead of `@Part`. Just change the API interface like below,

```
@Multipart
@POST(UPDATE_PROFILE)
Call<SignUp> sendUpdateProfileRequest(
        @Part("profile_img") RequestBody img_file,
        @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params,  /* notice the change here */
        ...
);
```

And use it like so,

```
... // code
Map<String, RequestBody> params = new HashMap<>();

// prepare RequestBody
RequestBody someDataBody = ....;

// add it Map object
params.put("DYNAMIC_PARAM_NAME", someDataBody);

// pass it to request
FooApiInterface api = ....;

Call<FooResponse> call = api.sendUpdateProfileRequest(imageFile, params);
call.enqueue({/* implement response listener */});
```

That should do the trick for you.